# Bluetooth headset keeps disconnecting on fedora

Tags: linux, fedora, bluetooth, intel

I am using fedora on my machine, the wifi/bluetooth card I am using is  **TP-Link WiFi 6 AX3000**, when I connect my headset **PXC 550 Wireless - Sennheiser** it works fine until it's idle then it gets disconnected.

result of **systemctl status bluetooth**:

```
Jan 10 22:06:32 lab bluetoothd[1530343]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_16_94_28_CA_31/sep1/fd7: fd(39) ready
Jan 10 22:11:36 lab bluetoothd[1530343]: profiles/audio/avdtp.c:cancel_request() Suspend: Connection timed out (110)
Jan 10 22:11:46 lab bluetoothd[1530343]: profiles/audio/avdtp.c:cancel_request() Suspend: Connection timed out (110)
Jan 10 22:11:48 lab bluetoothd[1530343]: profiles/audio/avdtp.c:cancel_request() Abort: Connection timed out (110)
Jan 10 22:12:19 lab bluetoothd[1530343]: src/profile.c:ext_io_disconnected() Unable to get io data for Hands-Free Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpo>
Jan 10 22:12:29 lab bluetoothd[1530343]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
Jan 10 22:13:10 lab bluetoothd[1530343]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_16_94_28_CA_31/sep1/fd8: fd(42) ready
Jan 10 22:34:35 lab bluetoothd[1530343]: profiles/audio/avdtp.c:cancel_request() Suspend: Connection timed out (110)
Jan 10 22:34:45 lab bluetoothd[1530343]: profiles/audio/avdtp.c:cancel_request() Suspend: Connection timed out (110)
Jan 10 22:34:47 lab bluetoothd[1530343]: profiles/audio/avdtp.c:cancel_request() Abort: Connection timed out (110)
```

one thing I've tried:

```bsh
$ sudo echo "options snd-hda-intel model=generic" >> /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
$ systemctl restart bluetooth.service
```

and still facing the same issue,

i have Fedora 35, kernel 5.14.18-300